# Mask input formate for decimal 3 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-inputmask

I stuck with input mask format for decimal 3 digits.

**For example, if user input 1 then it should be automatically formatted to 0.001 if user input 11 then it should be 0.011 means input digit start from right to left but I need to maintain 3 digits after "." and before the decimal point, the user can input infinite value. means if user input 11111 than it should be 11.111 and if user input 111111 than it should be 111.111.**

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: `I stuck with` Post what you've tried and we can help you get unstuck.

Comment: all you need to do just use the value multiple by 0.001?

Comment: Thanks @Dean i checked this in calculator it's work fine but any way in input mask Jquery plugins.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to format number in decimal for `1,2,3 etc. digits.` Please use `toFixed()` function as:

```
var input =  111;
input = input.toFixed(3);
console.log(input);
output: 111.000
```

But here your requirement is different. As **Dean** said, You can multiply by 0.001 to the given number as:

```
var input = 111;
input = input*0.001;
console.log(input);
output: 0.111;
```

Comment: your logic is correct it's work but i want it in text field like input mask.